# download and save image on device from link ionic app web view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I have an ionic web app and in my app, i want to download and save an image to my laptop or my mobile device if the app is viewed using a mobile device.

currently i have this code but while it downloads the image, the image has errors and hence cannot be viewed.

```
  $scope.download=function()
  {
      $http.get('http://mcgivery.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/IMG_0308.png', {responseType: "arraybuffer"}).success(function(data){

           var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array( data );
           var blob = new Blob( [ arrayBufferView ], { type: "image/png" } );
           var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
           var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL( blob );

           SaveToDisk(imageUrl,'abc.png');

        }).error(function(err, status){})
  }
  function SaveToDisk(fileURL, fileName) {
    // for non-IE
    if (!window.ActiveXObject) {
        var save = document.createElement('a');
        save.href = fileURL;
        save.target = '_blank';
        save.download = fileName || 'unknown';

        var event = document.createEvent('Event');
        event.initEvent('click', true, true);
        save.dispatchEvent(event);
        (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);
    }

    // for IE
    else if ( !! window.ActiveXObject && document.execCommand)     {
        var _window = window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
        _window.document.close();
        _window.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, fileName || fileURL)
        _window.close();
    }
  }
```

does anyone know how i can download and save the image on my laptop or on my mobile device. My ionic app is a WEB APP NOT A MOBILE OR PHONEGAP APP SO I CANT USE CORDOVA.

Thanks for your help

Comment: use $cordovafiletransfer.download for downloading the image

Comment: its a web app not a phonegap app @Anilkumar